# How to link image in dynamicPDF plugin in HTTPS

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, octobercms, dynamicpdf

I am generating dynamic PDF for the user in which i am printing the images of user gallery it was working fine in shared hosting with HTTP but not working in AWS EC2, it show "image not found or unknown type"?

Comment: So your site is HTTPS, are you trying to get the images over HTTP or HTTPS?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't done this. [Documentation](https://octobercms.com/plugin/renatio-dynamicpdf) here says you need to set the option `'isRemoteEnabled' => true`.

```
return PDF::loadTemplate('renatio::invoice', ['file' => $file])
->setOptions(['isRemoteEnabled' => true])
->stream();
```

Test your link to the image outside of the PDF. For using Dynamic PDF I test my layouts and templates both in normal html and PDF code. That helps me debug most errors. Not that the html and PDF stream are 100% similar but close enough.